# How to show result decimal style not exponential?

Tags: ios, swift, decimal, number-formatting

I tried to convert a value to another (from angstrom to arshin, a Russian ancient value of length), but often I got result in exponential style `1.837684e-10`. I need to show it in decimal style `0.0000000001837`.

The code I use:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal

if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

     angstrem = number.doubleValue

     arshin = Double(angstrem * 7112000000.0000)

     arshinLabel.text = "\(arshin)"
}
```

Adding this line is got nothing:

```
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
```

**UPD**
Full code down there:

import UIKit

class AngstremViewController: UIViewController {

```
var angstrem: Double = 0
var arshin: Double = 0
var versta: Double = 0
var vershok: Double = 0
var decimetr: Double = 0
var duim: Double = 0
var kilometr: Double = 0
var metr: Double = 0
var mili: Double = 0
var millimetr: Double = 0
var mormil: Double = 0
var sajen: Double = 0
var santimetr: Double = 0
var fut: Double = 0
var yard: Double = 0



@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!




//Result labels
@IBOutlet weak var angstremLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var arshinLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var verstaLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var vershokLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var decimetrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var duimLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var kilometrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var metrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var miliLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var millimetrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mormiliLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sajenLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var santimetrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var futLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yardLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red:47/255.0, green:158/255.0, blue:249/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let doneButon = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneClicked))


    toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButon], animated: true)

    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}



@objc func doneClicked() {
    view.endEditing(true)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal

    if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

        angstrem = number.doubleValue

        arshin = Double(angstrem * 0.00000000014060742)
        versta = Double(angstrem * 0.00000000000009373828270000001)
        vershok = Double(angstrem * 0.0000000022497188)
        decimetr = Double(angstrem * 0.000000001)
        duim = Double(angstrem * 0.0000000039370078700000005)
        kilometr = Double(angstrem * 0.0000000000001)
        metr = Double(angstrem * 0.0000000001)
        mili = Double(angstrem * 0.000000000000062137119)
        millimetr = Double(angstrem * 0.0000001)
        mormil = Double(angstrem * 0.00000000000005399568)
        sajen = Double(angstrem * 0.000000000046869141)
        santimetr = Double(angstrem * 0.00000001)
        fut = Double(angstrem * 0.00000000032808399)
        yard = Double(angstrem * 0.00000000010936132999999999)

        arshinLabel.text = "\(arshin)"
        verstaLabel.text = "\(versta)"
        vershokLabel.text = "\(vershok)"
        decimetrLabel.text = "\(decimetr)"
        duimLabel.text  = "\(duim)"
        kilometrLabel.text = "\(kilometr)"
        metrLabel.text = "\(metr)"
        miliLabel.text = "\(mili)"
        millimetrLabel.text = "\(millimetr)"
        mormiliLabel.text = "\(mormil)"
        sajenLabel.text = "\(sajen)"
        santimetrLabel.text = "\(santimetr)"
        futLabel.text = "\(fut)"
        yardLabel.text = "\(yard)"

    }
}
```

}

If i convert this

```
let number = formatter.number(from: text)
```

to

```
let number = formatter.String(from: number)
```

I've got errors.
I understand method but in all cases it doesn't working.

Could someone help with it?

Comment: Your "number to text" conversion does not use the NumberFormatter at all ...

Comment: And how i must show result in label without "number to text"? i've got a lot of errors this way

Comment: You need to change `arshinLabel.text = "\(arshin)"` to `arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: number)`

Comment: Note that Swift allows many unicode characters in variable names: `ångström`

Comment: @DávidPásztor but i have a lot of another values (like meters, kilometers...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @matic-oblak !

The solution is:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 6



        if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {


            angstrem = number.doubleValue


            arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: angstrem).multiplying(by: 0.00000000014060742))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So first of all what you did does not use a formatter at all (as already mentioned by @Martin R). You need to use `formatter.string(from: <#number#>)`. But it will not work this way either, it will most likely display "0". To simulate your result you would need to use `.scientific` style.

So what you are looking for is `.decimal` style that includes `minimumFractionDigits` which will force displaying a number of digits you need. Another probably better way is using `minimumSignificantDigits`. This will always show at least N digits that are non-zero (kind-of, `1001` still counts as 4 non-zero).

Another issue is that when dealing with such values you should not be using `double` at all. You need `NSDecimalNumber` which is designed for precision and large values.

Check this following example that combines it all:

```
let firstValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.0000000001837")
let secondValue: NSDecimalNumber = 0.00001

let overallValue = firstValue.multiplying(by: secondValue)

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = .current
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 4

if let text = formatter.string(from: overallValue) {
    print(text)
}
```

This will print the result of `0,000000000000001837`. If I increase `minimumSignificantDigits` to `6` then the result will be `0,00000000000000183700`.

Comment: In case with formatter.string I've got error:"Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'"

Comment: @IvanKisin You will need to be a bit more specific, maybe add the code that produces this error. Anyway it seems like you are expecting an `NSNumber` somewhere but are having a string like `let myNumber: NSNumber = myString`. The fix for this might again be: `let myNumber: NSNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: myString)`

Comment: however your solution isn't work. Im updated code in topic. Maybe you will see another mistakes, that ruins everything...

Comment: @IvanKisin you are completely misunderstanding what we are trying to tell you. The problem is NOT where you garb the value from text field but where you convert it back to string. The point is to convert `arshinLabel.text = "\(arshin)"` to `arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: number)`. Your first formatter is not needed at all as you may simply use `NSDecimalNumber(string: textField.text)`. So for instance: `arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(string: textField.text).multiplying(by: 0.00000000014060742))`

Comment: it's working but now formatter takes only integer part from entered number and multiply it to 0.00000000014060742

Comment: @IvanKisin That is a pity. I assume the issue is that constructor expects “.” and your string uses “,” as a separator. Use another formatter the way you did previously and creat an NSNumber with it. Then use appropriate constructor with NSDecimalNumber. So something like NSDecimalNumber(number: inputFormatter.number(from: textField.text))...

Comment: Yes! It expects ".". Problem in that Decimal pad in my language contents ",". Last time i tried connect localise formatter to change it to "."

Comment: I added "angstrem = number.doubleValue" and "arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: angstrem).multiplying(by: 0.000324))" and its working!

Comment: @IvanKisin I still hate it you need to convert it to double value. How about using locale on decimal number as such: `arshinLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(string: textField.text, locale: Locale.current).multiplying(by: 0.00000000014060742))`. So this way you avoid input formatter and only use high precision number structures.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted you code in playground that you can find helpful:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
let text = "0.0000000001837"
//! Convert string to number
let number = formatter.number(from: text)!
// 1.837e-10
let stringFromNumber = formatter.string(from: number)
//0
// Set up maximum number of fractional digits in formatter
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 100
let fullStringFromNumber = formatter.string(from: number)
//"0.0000000001837"
let angstrem = number.doubleValue
let arshin = Double(angstrem * 7112000000.0000)
//1.3064744
let arshinNumber = NSNumber(value: arshin)
let arshinStr = formatter.string(from: arshinNumber)
//"1.3064744"
```